# DynamicSQL using sp_executesql Error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql, sp-executesql

I keep getting an error with the following stored procedure.  I had it working correctly using EXEC, then I switched to sp_executesql and I haven't been able to get it to execute. I keep getting the following error: Incorrect syntax near '@numberOfItems'.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.FetchResourcesToProcess
(
@tableName nvarchar(MAX),
@numberOfItems int
)
AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
        SET @SQL = N'Select TOP @numberOfItems * from ' + @tableName + N' where Active = 1 AND BeingProcessed = 0'
        EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@numberOfItems int', @numberOfItems
    END
```

Tablename is a string structured as follows: "[TABLENAME]".

Thanks

Comment: Do a select @SQL. Take the result and copy and paste it in SSMS and see if you can execute that. You'll get better error messaging.

Comment: You need to put parentheses around @numberOfItems: `N'Select TOP (@numberOfItems) * from '`

Answer (score 4):

You probably need to place number of items into the string the same way you are the table name
    SET @SQL = N'Select TOP ' + Convert(varchar(10),@numberOfItems) + '  * from ' + @tableName + N' where Active = 1 AND BeingProcessed = 0'

Answer (score 0):

**I think you can only use parameters for sp_executesql statement in positions where variables are allowed.**

```
use master;
declare @numberOfItems  int;
set @numberOfItems  =   2;
Select TOP @numberOfItems * from dbo.spt_values
```

> Incorrect syntax near '@numberOfItems'.

```
use master;
declare @table  varchar(max);
set @table  =   'dbo.spt_values';
Select * from @table
```

> Must declare the table variable "@table".

```
use master;
declare @numberOfItems  int;
set @numberOfItems  =   2;
Select TOP(@numberOfItems) * from dbo.spt_values
```

> (2 row(s) affected)

**Solution 1 (parenthesis, recommended):**

```
        SET @SQL = N'Select TOP(@numberOfItems) * from ' + @tableName + N' where Active = 1 AND BeingProcessed = 0'
```

**Solution 2 (concatenation, make sure to prevent SQL injection!):**

```
        SET @SQL = N'Select TOP '+cast(@numberOfItems as nvarchar(MAX))+' * from ' + @tableName + N' where Active = 1 AND BeingProcessed = 0'
        EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
```